# Using `SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings` binding in Rust cause `errSecInternalComponent`

Tags: macos, rust, security-framework

I'm writing an update to [Security framework crate](https://github.com/kornelski/rust-security-framework/tree/81600ef0cce4aa768f5006024ae6c7ab5560e583/security-framework) that is a bindings to apple Security.framework.

I added some functionalities as `SecCertificateAddToKeychain` without any problem but with `SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings` the result is always
`-2070 errSecInternalComponent` .

This is the full implementation:

```
use crate::base::SecCertificateRef;
use core_foundation_sys::array::CFArrayRef;
use core_foundation_sys::base::CFTypeRef;
use core_foundation_sys::base::OSStatus;

pub type SecTrustSettingsDomain = u32;

pub const kSecTrustSettingsDomainUser: SecTrustSettingsDomain = 0;
pub const kSecTrustSettingsDomainAdmin: SecTrustSettingsDomain = 1;
pub const kSecTrustSettingsDomainSystem: SecTrustSettingsDomain = 2;

pub type SecTrustSettingsResult = u32;

pub const kSecTrustSettingsResultInvalid: SecTrustSettingsResult = 0;
pub const kSecTrustSettingsResultTrustRoot: SecTrustSettingsResult = 1;
pub const kSecTrustSettingsResultTrustAsRoot: SecTrustSettingsResult = 2;
pub const kSecTrustSettingsResultDeny: SecTrustSettingsResult = 3;
pub const kSecTrustSettingsResultUnspecified: SecTrustSettingsResult = 4;

extern "C" {
    pub fn SecTrustSettingsCopyCertificates(
        domain: SecTrustSettingsDomain,
        certsOut: *mut CFArrayRef,
    ) -> OSStatus;
    pub fn SecTrustSettingsCopyTrustSettings(
        certificateRef: SecCertificateRef,
        domain: SecTrustSettingsDomain,
        trustSettings: *mut CFArrayRef,
    ) -> OSStatus;
    pub fn SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings(
        certificateRef: SecCertificateRef,
        domain: SecTrustSettingsDomain,
        trustSettingsDictOrArray: CFTypeRef,
    ) -> OSStatus;
}
```

And this is the way I call the function:

```
pub fn set_trust_settings(cert: &SecCertificate) -> Result<()>{
    let domain = kSecTrustSettingsDomainAdmin;
    let trust_settings: CFTypeRef = ptr::null_mut();
        cvt(unsafe {
            SecTrustSettingsSetTrustSettings(
                cert.as_CFTypeRef() as *mut _,
                domain,
                trust_settings,
            )
    })
}
```

**Notes**

- `sudo security add-trusted-certs [..]` works without any problem
- I want to add this function to allow users to add my app certificate programmatically without to add it each time manually, I want to implement the remove certificate too, to remove them after the session
- I'm on macos 13 with M2
- `sudo security authorizationdb write com.apple.trust-settings.admin allow` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1399119-sectrustsettingssettrustsettings#:%7E:text=when%20not%20running%20in%20a%20GUI%20environment), there is a line that specifies that this function only works when called in a **GUI environment**.

My solution was that to create a [minimal macos bundle app](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1) to be called when needed with:

```
tokio::process::Command::new("open").arg("./path/app_name.app")
```